# Add and remove class Jquery on click

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, seconds

Is there any way to add a class on click and then remove it after 2 or 3 seconds?
Thanks in advance

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: try using `.addClass`,`.removeClass()`,`setTimeout()`.

Comment: Yes, `var $this = $this.addClass('magic'); setTimeout(function() {$this.removeClass('magic');}, 3000);`

Comment: yeah its working thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#your_click_element_id").on('click', function()
{
    $(this).addClass("class_name");//or $("#id_of_whatever_you_want)
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('class_name');
    }, 2000);
});
```

`setTimout` will wait for 2000 ms and then execute the `.removeClass()`.

```
<style>
.class_name{
    ...
}
</style>
```